# Is it possible to get double precision values from PDF numbers using Quartz on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf, quartz-graphics

I'm reading numeric values from a PDF file on iOS using Quartz like so:

```
CGPDFReal number;
CGPDFArrayGetNumber(myarray, index, &number);
```

On iOS it appears that

```
typedef CGFloat CGPDFReal;
```

and

```
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
```

Unfortunately the numbers I'm reading have more precision than can be stored in a float and I'm loosing data.  Is it possible to read these values as double precision from within Quartz?  Or do I need to go to a completely new library for reading the data from the PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use another library to get the values as double.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no problem in treating real values from a PDF as `float` values.

PDF Reference states that

> To represent real numbers, Acrobat 6
>   uses IEEE single-precision
>   floating-point numbers, as described
>   in the IEEE Standard for Binary
>   Floating-Point Arithmetic (see the
>   Bibliography).

I can think of some advantages of using `double` values for intermediate calculations, but there is probably not much sense in using `double` for reading values from a PDF.

Comment: This is true, however in practice you'll find that some software stores extra precision in numeric values in PDFs.  It's useful to be able to read the extra data when it's available.

Comment: @Josh Knauer can you please share some examples of such files? I am a developer of a PDF library and always willing to inspect "non-standard" PDFs. :-)

Comment: I've come across them in geospatial PDFS, specifically in the GPTS and LPTS arrays.  Check out: http://www.cnv.org/GIS/CNV_OCP_F_Trail_System_44x36.pdf